# Django: How to get objects by date from many models?

Tags: python, django, sorting

3 differents models have a different datetime field:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    # some fields here
    date = models.DateField()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    # some fields here
    date = models.DateField()

class ModelC(models.Model):
    # some fields here
    date = models.DateField()
```

I'd like to get the 50 last objects using the date fields (whatever their class).
For now, it works but I'm doing it in a very innecient way as you can see:

```
all_a = ModelA.objects.all()
all_b = ModelB.objects.all()
all_c = ModelC.objects.all()

last_50_events = sorted(
        chain(all_a, all_b, all_c),
        key=attrgetter('date'),
        reverse=True)[:50]
```

How to do it un a efficient way (ie. without loading useless data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution - which i recommend you - load 50 objects of each type, sort, get first 50 (load 3 times more)

"Proper solution" can't be achieved in ORM with your current schema.
Probably easiest way is add new model with date and generic relation to whole model.

Theoretically you can also do some magic with union and raw queries, but all stuff like this is dirty with non trivial manual processing.

Comment: Easy solution could be a good alternative thx :) However, this solution require to do 4 sorts. Could it be actually slower than the `.all()` solution?

Comment: For small number of object it doesn't important. For large collection  loading all is bottleneck and it helps. If there is not where condition and if it is indexed by date it could be loaded directly from database already sorted.

In fact you don't need 4th sort in python, you can merge in linear time (simple pop always item with smallest date). But again, for 150 items it is not issue.